# How to update vertices duplicates in geometry? Three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to change vertex positions in my mesh. Seems like three js stores vertex duplicates for each vertex. In my case I have 4 duplicates and I am only able to change 1 using `mesh.geometry.vertices[i]`. When I change this value, three other duplicates remain. I tried to use `mesh.geometry.mergeVertices();` It works for `geometry.vertices` array and i get 4 times less positions in it. But the problem still exists and duplicates are not removed from the actual geometry on the screen. So the question is, how to change vertex position for, for example, box and get all the duplicates updated automatically. Here is some debug pictures:[vertices array after mergeVertices()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GCBW.png), [actual geometry array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh9jh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to set

```
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

and possibly

```
geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
```

after you do the modifications. That tells THREE to re-upload the vertex data to the GPU.